# Samba 4 as AD DC and non-domain worstations authorization problems

Tags: samba, samba4

I've inherited a big Samba AD infrastructure with mix of old Samba builds (from 4.3 to 4.7) based on old 32 bit FreeBSD that cannot be updated simply.

I have built a test lab with Samba 4 AD DC and full spectrum of client PCs - from Windows XP to Windows 10. Also I have a file server based on Nethserver (actually does not matter). It works as an AD member and have two shares: One owned by "Domain Admins" group and another one by "Domain Users".

Initially, Samba was 4.3 version. All PC's can join the domain and all work as expected. I've both - domain PC's (Windows Pro) and non-domain (workgroup only PCs based on Windows Home edition).

There is no issue with the domain PC's.

On the non-domain PC's I've created exactly the same local user with the same password like a some domain user (for example 'User' with 'Passw0rd').

'winbind use default domain = yes' added to smb.conf

Now the experiment started:

On the Samba version 4.3 to 4.7 (including, any build) these PC's work 'like a domain members'. They can access shared folder on the server WITHOUT prompt of login/password.

Starting from Samba 4.8 non-domain PC's cannot authorize with this method.

There is the question - can I authorize on modern samba from NON-domain PC's **WITHOUT** prompting for a password? Or why does `winbind use default domain` not work as earlier? It's required 'by design' of the legacy configuration.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Any idea, please ...

Comment: No any ideas?... :'(